# iOS Photo Viewer with RSS

Tags: ios, rss, photo-gallery

I have a RSS-feed with the title en url of the photo, and I want to build in that pictures. What is the best way to do this? I Use MWPhotoBrowser and the way to insert photo's is:

```
self.photos = [NSMutableArray array];
[photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo2l" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
[photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3629/3339128908_7aecabc34b.jpg"]]];
[photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3590/3329114220_5fbc5bc92b.jpg"]]];
```

How to do this with RSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Photo Viewer from an RSS feed, I would suggest looking into [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser). You can easily grab the title and url of each item and display them however you'd like.

1 - Using MWFeedParser, parse your feed:

```
//feedURL would be your Photo RSS Feed
feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
```

2 - In the MWFeedParser delegate method didParseFeedItem, add the item's link to your photo array:

```
-(void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item{
    if (item) [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.link]]];
}
```

Now that the photos array contains all of your MWPhoto's, do whatever you'd like with them!

Comment: What I would do is use MWFeedParser to grab all of the links from the RSS feed and place the links into an NSMutableArray. Then for each URL in that array, add an object to the photos array:`[photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]];`

Comment: I gave you a bit of a guide with some code, let me know if you have any other questions! Don't forget to mark as answer if I've helped you!

Comment: What errors? I'm here to help no matter what. I'll help you get this figured out.

Comment: If you're using ARC, make sure that you mark those MWFeedParser files in your Build Phases with `-fno-objc-arc` in the Compilers Flags section next to the file names. That way, you won't get those errors.

Comment: Please see now my answer. :)